# Redirecting output from elevated process C#

Tags: c#, redirect

I need to run an elevated process from C#, and I need it to redirect input and output. Since doing all three is impossible, I think I may have come up with a workaround, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
        Process p = new Process();

        string command1 = "/s " + path + "\\script1.script";

        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("diskpart",command1)

        {

            UseShellExecute = true,

            CreateNoWindow = false,

            Verb="runas"

        };

        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
```

That works. It calls DiskPart with a script that just does `list volume`.
I want to capture the output from that into `outfile1.txt`.
When I run the following command from the terminal it works:
`diskpart /s script1.script>outfile1.txt`
However, when I modify `command1` to be `"/s " + path + "\\script1.script>+path+"\\outfile1.txt"` I get an error from DiskPart that it was unable to open or read my file.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Didn't find a solution, but I found a workaround.

I was trying to get the drive letter of a USB drive which I then wanted to set as readonly. However, using the `DriveInfo.Name` I was able to get it. (It would have been more helpful if that were called `DriveInfo.driveLetter`) Then I wrote my DiskPart script accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find a solution, but I found a workaround.

I was trying to get the drive letter of a USB drive which I then wanted to set as readonly. However, using the `DriveInfo.Nam`e I was able to get it. (It would have been more helpful if that were called `DriveInfo.driveLetter`) Then I wrote my DiskPart script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a syntax error in your command1.  You said you changed it to:

> "/s " + path + "\script1.script>+path+"\outfile1.txt"

and I think what you want is(missing one double quotation mark):

> "/s " + path + "\script1.script>" + path + "\outfile1.txt"

If that's not the case, what happens when you use your terminal command - "diskpart /s script1.script>outfile1.txt" - as command1?  You might want to look at this other stackoverflow topic for running commands in C#:

[Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)